# How to fix Invariant Violation: Minified React error #143 for CSSTransition from react-transition-group

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import PreviewPanel from "./containers/PreviewPanel";
import { CSSTransition  } from "react-transition-group";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <PreviewPanel></PreviewPanel>
        <CSSTransition></CSSTransition>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

It's Invariant Violation: Minified React error #143. When I remove the CSSTransition block, It's working correctly. please help me how to use CSSTransitoin without error?

Comment: can you show us your package.json? which react-transition-group version are you using? did you run npm install?

Comment: "react-transition-group": "^4.4.1",

Comment: Yes. I run npm install.

Comment: When you get a minified react error, you can see the full error by entering the error number in the React website's error decoder. For example, [error 143](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=143) is: `React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.`

Comment: `CSSTransition` is probably expecting a child, whereas in the code it has none.

Comment: I added the child . but It has a 143 error

Answer (score 0):

`CSSTransition` is expecting a child but you haven't given one: https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/blob/master/src/Transition.js#L400

```
children: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    PropTypes.element.isRequired,
  ]).isRequired,
```

The error should go away when you actually animate an element.